# Document word index database structure?

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing

Say I'm looking to recognize all the occurrences of a word amongst several pages of a document (probably around 500+ pages). I've already done the work of finding on which pages a word occurs. So for example I want to list all the pages where the word computer occurs.

What would be the best way to store this data to be quickly searchable via a web service? My instinct is to just do something like:

Table Structure:
varchar(30) WORD, blob PAGES

And have the PAGES field be a comma delimited list of all the pages where the word occurs and then just explode that and list all the pages when a query matches a WORD field. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do achieve this though? I'd likely be using MySQL and PHP/Zend just because that's what I'm most familiar with. But if you have any better ideas I'm definitely open to hearing them.

The table would likely get extremely long as I'd need a row for every unique word in the document. Perhaps I'd set a limit for nothing shorter than 3 or 4 characters but still I would imagine upwards of 10-20k words. Could I somehow make it easier on my database server if I alphabetized the row list? (ie. apple, apples, branch are in ascending order?) Can MySQL handle this? Could something else handle it better?

Lastly, are there better structure schemas that might later allow me to gather/provide interesting data? (i.e. give the user related words that often appear in close proximity, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to **normalize** you database.

First a table to store the pages

```
table pages (
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
  page blob,
  other_interesting_data_about_a_page )
```

Then a table to hold the word counts

```
table wc (
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key
  word varchar(20) unique key,
  count unsigned integer default 1,
  other_interesting_data_about_a_word.... )
```

Then a table to link words to pages

```
table word_page (
  word_id unsigned integer,
  page_id unsiged integer,
  pos_in_page unsigned integer,  /*position*/
  primary key pk (word_id, page_id, pos_in_page) )
```

Now you can query the number of words in a page:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM word_page 
WHERE page_id = 123
```

Or the number of times word 'the' is repeated in a page.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM word_page wp 
INNER JOIN wc ON (wp.word_id = wc.id)
WHERE wp.page_id = 123 AND wc.word = 'the'
```

**A word of warning**

> And have the PAGES field be a comma delimited list of all the pages.....

Never ever ever use CSV in a database, it is the worst anti-pattern you can ever use and it will bite you over and over if you fall for it.
If you ever feel the need, kick yourself in the head until the urge goes away, then use a separate table or two instead.

Comment: I'll never use CSV in a database. :) Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to normalizing, which is good practice in general but quite space-inefficient for this particular problem, you may want to stick to your structure but replace the list of pages in your blob by a vector of bits (still inside a blob column), each bit representing a page. The advantage is that for 500 pages, the maximum size of this vector for one word would be 63 bytes even if this word appears in all the pages (500/8=62.5).

Inside the bitfield, each page corresponds to a bit number: if bit number N is ON, it means that the word appears at page N, otherwise it doesn't appear at page N.
This is the structure that is basically used by [DBIx SQL text indexing implementation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-TextIndex/lib/DBIx/TextIndex.pm)
Bits are numbered right to left, and non-significant 0's can be removed.

For example if the word "computer" is present in pages 3,4 and 12 the value would be:
`100000001100` in binary (=2060 in decimal representation).

If it appears only at page 400, it would be the digit `1` followed by 399 `0's`. If it appears on every page, the value would be 500 times the digit `1`.

I've been using that representation (plus partitioning) for full-text-indexing mail contents in a postgresql database and I've found it to scale very well, contrary to the naive normalized implementation that performs well only for very small datasets.

Comment: Never would have considered something like this, thanks! I think Johan's answer though more costly will allow me to do more interesting things with the stored data down the line though.

Comment: @Emeka (as well), nice idea David, However don't be temped to denormalize **before** you run into speed/space problems. I wonder how you deal with words that occur more than once on a page (but I'm getting in too deep now).

Answer (score 1):

for easier maintenance and indexing, i would set up a mapping table with a computed primarey key:
id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
word VARCHAR(30),
page INT, 
...
and build an index for both word and page. 
This way, you are more flexible, don't need to explode the list and even get access to some statistics (which pages use more unique words etc).

MySQL (and every other relational DB engine) builds it own internal index using tree structures, there is no need to pre sort your data.

This table is easily handled by MySQL. there may be other DB Engines that are even faster, but it's an ok start.

of course you could add more tables, ie word, other_word, distance, it all depends on your specification and what is possible with your parser.

if you have some time to browse around, take a look at how searchengines, for example solr/lucene are handling this things

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Solr/Lucene. Might end up going in this direction!